# Traffic fall after a server problem

Tags: seo, google, server, search-engine-indexing

I have a website from which I analyse the traffic with Google analytics.
Day after day the traffic (mainly from Google SE) incresed until I get a problem with my server.
For one day the server has been offline and after that I have no longer had as much users as I had before. Now it's like the site is no more referenced on Google index (but when I type "site:mysite.com", I still have all the results).

Do you know if this is a normal behaviour and if the traffic will come back as before (the server has had problems two days ago) ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that the traffic sourcing from Google in Google Analytics has declined, not just in general?

Comment: Yes, the drop is exclusively for Google. I still have traffic from referring sites. I say "in Google Analytics" because this is my analytic tool, but it concord with my own tool to log the requests.

Comment: No reply to my answer? Not even a comment? If either answer below is accurate, please use the checkmark to highlight which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clearly been penalized, thus the fall on traffic. **A whole day with the server down its a lot of time**.

For sites from about 2000 pages Google crawls some pages of the site almost every day for changes, several times a day. If no changes are found in time, it crawls them less frequently. So, all of the crawled pages in that day have changed from quality content to 404/500 page content.

Indexed `404`'s and `500`'s are really bad for SEO as they get very penalized by Google, even more if they are not informative (soft) error pages.

First of all, **make sure you've fixed your server problems**, you don't want `500`'s to get crawled again.

As time passes, your pages, will get back near to their original position, some in days, some in weeks, some in months.

A **laborious trick** is to change your site's appearance/distribution, Google will crawl way more pages a day than it does normally to keep the site *fresh* in SERPs.

Another thing you can do is to add your `sitemap.xml` (if you haven't done it already), Google loves them and may crawl the pages in it for the first time earlier than normal.

Ps: `site:mysite.com` is not updated in real time. It's just useful to give you an approach of your site's index in Google.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible explanations;

- Your site is in quarantine. I.e. the site is still indexed, but it's not displayed (or ranking is significantly decreased). This is a temporary thing but it can last for months if you're unlucky. Google sometimes does this to sites that have been behaving "suspiciously", i.e. in the event of a takeover or so.
- It could also be that your site is new and **had** a high position in the SERPs, but as a test. Google sometimes does this to test if their users respond well to new websites.

Those are the reasons I can think of. I suspect it's the first as the second is uncommon. In this case it will come back eventually, thought I have no idea on how long it will take. As I said, it can sometimes take quite a while. Just keep the site active and ranking will resume.

I do suggest you get a Google Webmaster Tools account and start analyzing your site there as well. Google Analytics is not great for technical analysis.

Hope that helps.